# How to Upload metapackage in marketplace?

Tags: magento2, theme, extensions, composer, marketplace

I'm trying to upload a theme on Marketplace. I have uploaded dependent module packages in shared packages section and my main theme package in the theme section.

Theme should call other shared modules. How can I achieve this ? should I need to upload theme package as shared package as well?
How can meta package composer.json file help me? how can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your dependant packages in the `require` part of your theme.

Take a look at the `require` part of the `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/composer.json` file :

```json
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": "~8.1.0||~8.2.0",
        "magento/framework": "*"
    },
    ...
```

You can see that the theme requires two packages :

- `php`
- `magento/framework`

In your own composer.json, add your additional package in this section, so composer will know they are needed in order for your theme to work.

Comment: Marketplace throws errors when I mention my shared packages name in the required part of composer.json file of theme  https://ibb.co/drQ8Qtm

Comment: Do you have more details about the error reports ? What are the error described exactly ?

Comment: This is how I'm trying to call my shared module in the theme file https://ibb.co/qFDjkjk

Comment: It just shows this line in error report https://ibb.co/xGRFcZQ